# What does "mad fish" mean in Bring The Pain by Method Man?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, terminology, rap

In the song "Bring The Pain" by Method Man, he says:

> Check it, just how deep can shit get/
> Deep as the abyss/
> and brothers is mad fish accept it

What does "mad fish" mean in this context?

This appears in the uncensored version of the song.

Answer (score 1):

Would likely be slang/word play on "very suspect" as the line refers to explaining just how deep shit can get, not literally but metaphorically with double meaning.